# Sails API: blueprint pagination - custom implementation

Tags: api, pagination, sails.js

So I would like to implement more straight forward pagination with sails and instead of skip using currentPage or just page...

So, I already implemented a custom find action that replaces the default one ...
https://github.com/randallmeeker/SailsBluePrintActions

this one populates the additional info object on response

Here is the source
https://github.com/randallmeeker/SailsBluePrintActions/blob/master/pagination/inBody/find.js

So what I did, I added this

```
module.exports = function findRecords(req, res) {
    // definde page if exists
    var page = req.param("page", null);
    ....
    if (page) {
        query = Model.find()
            .where(actionUtil.parseCriteria(req))
            .paginate({
                page: page,
                limit: actionUtil.parseLimit(req)
            })
            .sort(actionUtil.parseSort(req));

    } else {
        query = Model.find()
            .where(actionUtil.parseCriteria(req))
            .limit(actionUtil.parseLimit(req))
            .skip(actionUtil.parseSkip(req))
            .sort(actionUtil.parseSort(req));
    }
```

The problem is, that I get page as a query parameter (sails search parameter)... and I would like to remove it from the list of parameters

so I tried something like:

```
var page = req.param("page", null);
if(page){
    console.log(page);
    delete req.query.page;
}
```

but sails still searches by the term page..

what would be the proper way to do this?

Comment: I found there is a black list defined in sails qhen parsingthe params
req.options.criteria.blacklist ... so will just add it there.. I think this will solve it

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and I solved it thanks to your code, by adding a couple of things:

1. Initializing the blacklist before calling parseCriteria in your code, adding the 'page' word as follows:

   ```
   module.exports = function findRecords(req, res) {
       // define page if exists
       var page = req.param("page");
       ....

       // Allow customizable blacklist for params NOT to include as criteria.
       req.options.criteria = req.options.criteria || {};
       req.options.criteria.blacklist = req.options.criteria.blacklist || ['page', 'limit', 'skip', 'sort', 'populate'];

       if (page) {
       ...
   ```

This will avoid using the 'page' slug as a where condition.

2. Create a custom parseSkip function in the blueprint module as follows:

   ```
   /**
    * parseSkip is a function that overrides the behavior of the original from actionUtil,
    * to allow the case a param 'page' is set in the request / query string
    * @param  {Request} req
    */

   function parseSkip(req) {
       var DEFAULT_SKIP = 0;
       var skip = DEFAULT_SKIP;
       if (req.param('skip') || (typeof req.options.skip !== 'undefined'))
           skip = +req.param('skip');
       else if (req.param('page') || (typeof req.options._page !== 'undefined')) {
           skip = req.param('page') * actionUtil.parseLimit(req) - actionUtil.parseLimit(req);
       }
       return skip;
   };
   ```

This will allow avoiding the if sentence and leave the code as it was. So, the equivalent final part of your code will be as follows:

```
module.exports = function findRecords(req, res) {
        ...
        // Allow customizable blacklist for params NOT to include as criteria.
        req.options.criteria = req.options.criteria || {};
        req.options.criteria.blacklist = req.options.criteria.blacklist || ['limit', 'page', 'skip', 'sort', 'populate', 'order'];

        // Lookup for records that match the specified criteria
        var query = Model.find()
            .where(actionUtil.parseCriteria(req))
            .limit(actionUtil.parseLimit(req))
            .skip(parseSkip(req))
            .sort(actionUtil.parseSort(req));

        query.exec(function found(err, matchingRecords) {
            ...
```

I wish it can help somebody!